# How to get information of a one-dimensional array if there are two-dimensional coordinates?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a two-dimensional array.

```
let x = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]
```

I use the Array.flat() method and get a one-dimensional array

```
let y = x.flat();
```

Can I use two-dimensional coordinates to get information from one-dimensional?
let's say my coordinates are [1] [3]. Using these coordinates, how can I get information from the y array.

Comment: So, you want to get the value of `x[1][3]` from `y`?

Comment: @ Jack Bashford Yes, I want to get the value from y, using the coordinates [1] [3]

Comment: it is possible only if the length or number of subarrays is known, or if x is square

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that all subarrays have the same length, denoted `N` below, you can use this formula:

```
i * N + j
```

That is:

```
x[i][j] is equal to y[i * N + j]
```

```js
let x = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]];

let y = x.flat();

let N = x[0].length; // length of subarrays (subarrays are assumed to be of equal length)

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
    console.log(x[i][j], ' === ', y[i * N + j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted to see. In my project there is only a y array and the coordinates [1] [3] .x array is missing.

Comment: @UncleRuckus Then how do you expect to get that information if you have nothing to start with? You must have at least the length of the subarrays if you want a precise answer.